# record update syntax, equal property names in different types

Tags: haskell

say there are two different types of trees:

```
data Tree1 = Tree1 {name :: String, color :: String} deriving Show
data Tree2 = Tree2 {name :: String, age :: Integer} deriving Show
```

and consider the following default values for each type:

```
defaultTree1 = Tree1 "No Name" "green"
defaultTree2 = Tree2 "No Name" 10
```

By using record update syntax, now it's possible to create instances of both types as followed. E.g:

```
defaultTree1 {color = "brown"}
-- >
Tree1 {name = "No Name", color = "brown"}
```

When trying this with only the name "property", it we get an error:

```
defaultTree1 {name = "My Tree"}
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Tree2’ with actual type ‘Tree1’
    In the expression: defaultTree1
    In the expression: defaultTree1 {name = "My Tree"}
```

However, it works with Tree2:

```
defaultTree2 {name = "My Tree"}
-- >
Tree2 {name = "My Tree", age = 10}
```

What's the reason for this? How could an instance of Tree1 being created by using some default values?

Comment: Are you using `DuplicateRecordFields`? Those two definitions are not legal together without it.

Comment: No, I just tried it in the ghci (which I think just overrides the previous definition in this case) . I'm getting an error when using a source file.

Comment: If it's like this, I understand the behavior.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like it would explain what’s going on here.

Comment: Yup, it is just the definition being shadowed in GHCi. By the way, loading the data type definitions from a source file with `DuplicateRecordFields` enabled and trying to use them as shown here leads to `Record update is ambiguous, and requires a type signature`, [which is also expected](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#duplicate-record-fields).